# Why was my "Not an answer" flag declined in this instance?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179285/variable-number-of-arguments-in-pl-sql-stored-procedure) and saw that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179285/variable-number-of-arguments-in-pl-sql-stored-procedure/41065382#41065382) didn't appear to address the OP's question at all.

So as I read it, the question was whether a procedure can take a variable number of arguments and [Bill Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7273781/bill-myers)' answer doesn't talk about arguments at all.

I went ahead and flagged the answer as "Not an answer":

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not attempt to answer the
>   question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

I felt this answer fell into the bolded description above of not attempting to answer the question.

However, my flag has been declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I don't believe I was highlighting technical inaccuracies and the answer was only "wrong" in the sense that I don't believe it answered the question which was being asked.

So, why was my flag declined? Did I totally misunderstand this question and actually this answer is a legitimate response to the question?

I see that [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/5669294) suggests:

> Any post that attempts to answer the question, however badly is still
>   an answer.

Does the answer I tried to flag count as attempting to answer the question? If so, where is the line drawn?

Comment: Because it looks like an answer; it's about context, and there is no context in that flag dialog.

Comment: "where is the line drawn?" The truth is that there is not a line, but a massive *gulf*.

Comment: @BoltClock could you explain? Do you mean that it's very obvious when this flag should be used and when it shouldn't? Is the fact that the answer I flagged looks like an answer at a glance enough to make it ineligible to be flagged as not an answer, despite the fact that (I believe) it doesn't provide any kind of answer to the question which was asked?

Comment: To give an extreme example, if someone asked "How do I use `GROUP BY` in SQL?" and someone answered "Here is how you use `ORDER BY` in SQL...etc...", would that answer also be ineligible to be flagged as "Not an answer" because it technically is an answer, but just not to the question which was asked?

Comment: That answer looks like a follow-up (or possibly an extended comment) to the other answer, and not meant to address the original question. By that token it's a bad answer, but not a Not An Answer.

Comment: @RadLexus really? That sounds to me like it falls squarely into "It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**..." from the description for the flag itself?

Comment: It is not that unusual for somebody to assume the question to be more than the stoopid RTFM it reads like.  So they'll look for a deeper reason between the lines, those guesses are not exactly always good ones.  It can happen, it didn't.  We'll get it deleted.

Comment: Not An Answer: "hey @3N1GM4 do you know how to foo the bar .."; Not An Answer: "the accepted answer does not work for me"; Not An Answer: "v1agra v1agra c1al1s free d0wnl0adz t0rrentz t0rrentz click here"

Comment: @3N1GM4: It means that there is no consensus on what makes an answer truly NAA beyond the most egregious cases. Most will agree that the answer you cite is borderline, but some will tell you that your flag will get declined for that reason, others will tell you that your flag should have been approved, and so on. Personally, I'm in the "avoid using NAA for answers that seem even remotely on-topic" camp.

Comment: @RadLexus ok, so anything that **looks like an answer** should not be flagged as "Not an Answer", even if it doesn't at all attempt to answer the original question?

Comment: Flagging as NAA is like playing roulette. You don't know how will it go until you flag it.